# Capture current user custom field and save in database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm using a custom membership provider. I'm trying to capture a custom field called *FirstName* which is in the *Users* table. I have another table called *Pages* which is used to store newly created pages in my application. I'm using a repository pattern and want to assign the current user's first name to each new Page that is created by a user.

I've created a base controller that is meant to capture the current user's first name and output as ViewData. How do I then pass the ViewData content to the repository and store it in the database?

Here's my base controller:

```
public abstract class ApplicationController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        if (User != null)
        {
            var db = new applicationContext();
            var username = User.Identity.Name;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
            {
                var user = db.UserProfiles.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == username);
                string firstName = string.Concat(new string[] { user.FirstName });
                ViewData.Add("FirstName", firstName);
            }
        }
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }
}
```

This controller inherits from the ApplicationController:

```
private applicationRepository repository = new applicationRepository();

public ActionResult Create(PageViewModel issue)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        page.PageId = repository.Page(page);
    }

    return Json(new[] { issue });
}
```

This is my repository pattern:

```
private applicationContext db = new applicationContext();

public int CreatePage(PageViewModel viewModel)
{
    var page = new Page();
    viewModel.CopyToIssue(page);

    db.Issues.Add(issue);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return issue.IssueId;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make a base viewmodel class and put a property FirstName on the base viewModel.  In the controller you could then add the FirstName from the viewdata to the FirstName property on the viewmodel.

OR

Instead of using viewdata make a property on your base controller for FirstName and then copy that onto you viewmodel